# Delete file from isolated storage without checking for existance before

Tags: c#, isolatedstorage

I've seen some lines in one of our applications looking like this:

```
if (isolatedStore.FileExists(firstFilePath))
    isolatedStore.DeleteFile(firstFilePath);
if (isolatedStore.FileExists(secondFilePath))
    isolatedStore.DeleteFile(secondFilePath);
```

Do I really have to check if a file exists in isolated storage prior to deletion or can I delete it directly without any changes in functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the files without checking if they are there, as long as you are prepared to handle any resulting exceptions: from [How to: Delete Files and Directories in Isolated Storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx3852wf(v=vs.110).aspx)

> An IsolatedStorageException exception is thrown if you try to delete a file or directory that does not exist.

Comment: So it isn't possible to delete multiple files one after another without checking if just one of it doesn't exist?

Comment: It depends on your circumstances. If you create files in batches, then checking that just the first one exists may be enough.

Answer (score 1):

No, just put a try block so no exceptions affect your application.

```
try { isolatedStore.DeleteFile(filePath); } catch { }
```

Or you can check if an error occurred, and handle the exception:

```
try
{
    isolatedStore.DeleteFile(filePath);
}
catch (IsolatedStorageException ex)
{
    // Handle the exception however you want...
}
```